# Evidence file.pdf - evidence not found

Tags: terminal, evince

I have in bash file:

```
evidence file.pdf
```

and an error command evidence not found. What should I install and what evidence command do? Thanks

Comment: This was probably meant to say `evince`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should probably be

```
evince file.pdf
```

to start [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince), the GNOME document viewer.

If you have GNOME installed, Evince should already be installed. If it isn’t, install your distribution’s `evince` package.